# CSS Align hr to the left

Tags: css

I want to align the hr divider to the left. I've tried `align-items: left;` , `align-content: left;` and `text-align:left;` but none of them are working.

```css
hr.divider {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="divider">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget magna in sem sagittis imperdiet sed at nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiama turpis arcu, blandit quis mattis ut, tempus ac metus. Sed efficitur risus non erat facilisis aliquet.</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `margin: 0;` to `hr.divider`.

This is because, default margin value for `hr` is `margin: 0 auto;` since `hr` is a block element. Reset that to `margin: 0;` via css.

```css
hr.divider {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<hr class="divider">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget magna in sem sagittis imperdiet sed at nunc.
Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiama turpis arcu, blandit quis mattis ut, tempus ac metus. Sed efficitur risus non erat
facilisis aliquet.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to make your element `inline`, which will make it start aligning horizontally because no line breaks before and after.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#grouped_values

```css
hr.divider {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="divider">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget magna in sem sagittis imperdiet sed at nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiama turpis arcu, blandit quis mattis ut, tempus ac metus. Sed efficitur risus non erat facilisis aliquet.</p>
```

Also, I suggest you find articles about CSS alignments and start using flex.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/03/css-alignment/

Answer (score 0):

Just Align the `hr` to left and you are done.

```css
hr.divider {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  width: 30px;
  
}
```

```html
<hr class="divider" align = "left">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget magna in sem sagittis imperdiet sed at nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiama turpis arcu, blandit quis mattis ut, tempus ac metus. Sed efficitur risus non erat facilisis aliquet.</p>
```